# Nodejs logging middleware log only once

Tags: javascript, node.js

My nodejs express app serves a file that requires and loads css files, js files, etc. I have a logging middleware that requests the ip of a client and logs said ip (after checking it doesn't match to a json file of malicious ips). Because of the resources the server loads, when a person loads a page once, the server will log the ip many times.

logging middleware:

```
function checkIP(req, res, next) {
  const clientIp = req.ip;
  let allowCXN = true;

//read json file
fs.readFile("ip_info.json", "utf8", function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      var ip_info = JSON.parse(data);

      for (let i = 0; i <= ip_info.ip_array.length - 1; i++) {
        //console.log(ip_info.ip_array[i].ip);
        if (clientIp == ip_info.ip_array[i].ip) {
          allowCXN = false;
        }
      }

      if (!allowCXN) {
          res.end();
          next();
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Now serving ip:", "\x1b[33m", clientIp, "\x1b[37m");
        next();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The ip is also being logged to a separate json file to keep track of who has connected, this fills up the json array with the same ip over and over, rather than just once. Is there a way to only log the ip once for one connection rather than for each connection to all other required files?

JSON file as requested:

```
{
  "ip_array": [
    {
      "ip": "::ffff:198.23.172.233",
      "unauth_joins": 0
    },
    {
      "ip": "::ffff:64.62.197.182",
      "unauth_joins": 0
    },
    {
      "ip": "::ffff:23.148.145.235",
      "unauth_joins": 0
    },
    {
      "ip": "::1",
      "unauth_joins": 0
    },
    {
      "ip": "::ffff:127.0.0.1",
      "unauth_joins": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share how your JSON looks like? Why don't you create IP address as key in the JSON which is unique in itself and before adding the same IP again check if it exist in the JSON file. However, you might need to find a way to keep this data in memory as it is expensive to read file every time user request data .

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I have edited my post to include my json file. I added a function that loops through ip_info.ip_array.length and returns true if the ip is present. Using this I added an if statement that checks if the function returned as false. If so, I push in the req.ip to the array and move to the next process. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const ip_info = JSON.parse(data);

   for (let i = 0; i <= ip_info.ip_array.length - 1; i++) {
        //console.log(ip_info.ip_array[i].ip);
        const result = ip_info.ip_array.find(el => el.ip === 'userIPAddress');
        if(result) {
          // it means IP exist don't append in the data
        } else {
          // add to the array
        }
      }
```

There could be other ways too like adding IP address as key in the object or you can use `Map` DS from the JS native, it is efficient for searching.